# Instantiating twig in a namespaced class

Tags: php, namespaces, twig

I'm running into some issues trying to figure out how to use Twig in a specific way. I'm trying to write a view class that I can use in my application regardless of what template system is installed, that way the only things I would have to change would be the templates themselves and the view class.

However, when I try and create the twig objects in the class, I get `Fatal error: Class 'Template\Twig_Loader_Filesystem' not found` errors, and I'm not really sure what I'm missing.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Here's what I've got so far...

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "Movies",
    "description": "Find movies",
    "require": {
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "twig/twig": "~1.0"
   },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/classes"
        ]
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
require_once 'app/app.php';
use Template\Template;

echo Template::render('hello.html', array('name' => 'bob', 'age' => '33'));
```

**app/app.php**

```
define('APP_DIRECTORY', __DIR__ . '/..');
require_once APP_DIRECTORY . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

**app/classes/Template.class.php**

```
namespace Template;

class Template {

    static function render($template_name, $template_data = array()) {
        $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(APP_DIRECTORY . '/app/templates');
        $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

        return $twig->render('hello.html', array('name' => 'lisa', 'age' => '33'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turned out whenever I would try and include the twig namespaces on my Template class, I was doing it wrong. Looking at other projects my organization has put together, it turns out just adding

```
use Twig_Environment;
use Twig_Loader_Filesystem;
```

to the class is enough. I wasn't sure if I actually had to add anything, since the Autoloader was included, or if I had to include part of the path, like `Twig_Twig/Loader/Filesystem` or something like that. Obviously neither of those was working.

Comment: This works, but the real problem: php assumed you meant `Template\Twig_Environment`. You can prefix a root-namespace class in a namespaced file like this: `\Twig_Environment`.